# Use the "security" keyword a property name in a definition in Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have an object in my definitions section that needs to have a property named security, but when i do this the swagger editor gives me the error message:

> Semantic error at definitions.User.properties.security.properties
>   security requirements must match a security definition
>   Jump to line 49

Here's my definition

```
definitions:
  Security:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
  User:
    type: object
    required: 
     - can
     - username
    properties:
      can:
        type: integer
        readOnly: true
      username:
        type: string
        format: email
        readOnly: true
      security:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Security'
```

Is there anything I can do this and avoid the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1343) was **fixed in Swagger Editor 3.2.0+** back in 2017.

The issue was that model properties named `security` were incorrectly flagged as part of security definitions. Actually `security` should be treated as a reserved keyword only when used on the global level or path level; it's OK to have a model property named `security`.

Comment: @LEQADA Please [ask a new question](/questions/ask?tags=swagger-editor) or open an issue in the Swagger Editor repository https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues

Comment: There is already an issue for it https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1604 . Closed for some reason.

Comment: @LEQADA Please [open a new issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues). Make sure to fill in the issue template and provide a sample OpenAPI YAML/JSON file to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in Swagger Editor that needs to be reported. What you have is perfectly fine with Old Swagger [Editor](http://editor2.swagger.io/) whereas the new Swagger [Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/) is reporting the issue you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I have also seen this tool that lets you build visually your API definitions and then export them to swagger (or import):

https://apibldr.com

Perhaps it can help you build your API definitions.